# Regex HTML comments (PCRE)

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the mediaID from an HTML block however I couldn't figure out a way to skip all the other parts and only get the mediaIDs within the HTML block?

```
<!-- wp:pdf-viewer-block/standard {"mediaID":5943} -->
```

I can select the HTML comment with the followings:

```
<!-- .* -->
```

Could you please show me a way to only get the mediaIDs?

Comment: Why bother with the comment at all? Isn't `{"mediaID":5943}` reasonably unique to match directly?

Comment: Indeed, your assumption is correct.

Answer (score -1):

The correct regex for solving this issue and getting that number:

```
<!-- wp:pdf-viewer-block.?standard {"mediaID":(.*?)} -->
```